# find outputs result but -exec ignores it

Tags: bash, find, rm

I wrote a simple command to find folders older than a month and delete them.
Here is the command :

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec bash -c 'rm -rfv "$0"' {} \;
```

It works fine in most cases, but sometime, the -exec "ignores" the result.
After running the command once, If I run the find without -exec, it still finds some folders older than a month which have not been removed.

I then tried with a simple echo and got no output :

```sh
$ find . -type d -mtime +31
./folder_A
./Folder_B
$ find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec bash -c 'echo  "$0"' {} \;
<No output>
```

I found a workround using grep but I'm wondering why the -exec ignores some results.
Anyone knows ?

Here is the workaround :

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 | grep . --color=never | while read line ; do rm -rvf "$line" ; done
```

Comment: `find -type d -mtime +31 -exec rm -rfv {} \;` or `find -type d -mtime +31 -delete`?

Comment: Very strange. Could it be that these folder names embed hidden characters that alter the behavior of `echo`? Did you try `cat -v <<< "$0"` instead of `echo  "$0"`?

Comment: @Cyrus: Doesn't work if the directory matches `-mtime +31` but the contained files don't -- the files do not get deleted, and the delete on the directory fails because it's not empty. AFAIK there is no "force" option for `find ... -delete`.

Comment: Side note: This is tremendously inefficient. Either `... -exec bash -c 'rm -rfv "$0" "$@"' {} +` or one of the better versions with `+` listed in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69585632/8584929) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your find commands seem a bit strange to me. I'd suggest changing:

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec bash -c 'rm -rfv "$0"' {} \;
```

to:

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec rm -rfv {} \;
```

or even better (increases performance):

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec rm -rfv {} +
```

---

If you insist on calling Bash explicitly (although I can't think of any reason why you should as `rm` is not a Bash built-in), I'd suggest changing:

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec bash -c 'rm -rfv "$0"' {} \;
```

to:

```
find . -type d -mtime +31 -exec bash -c 'rm -rfv {}' \;
```

---

Same goes for the find command containing `echo`.

Comment: you are right, I don't need bash anymore here (I was running multiple command here before I moved to that single command).

Comment: What's the effect of the "+" ? 
I never heard about it before.

Comment: @Airmoi: the `+` instructs `find` to pass everything it finds as one long argument list to the command specified by `-exec`. In other words, the command (here `rm`) is only run **once** with lots of arguments. When using `\;`, the command is run separately for each item found instead.

Comment: @Airmoi: Actually `+` *may* run the command multiple times -- if the argument list would get too long for the shell to handle. So you cannot *rely* on there only being one invocation.

Comment: @DevSolar: you're right of course, I intentionally left that part out to keep the explanation simple.